# Storing register values from a hook in assembly/c++ and save to array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64, hook, inline-assembly

I'm trying to make a hook that takes the rdi from a function and stores it in an array.
I know how to do it using inline assembly as by the code example:

```cpp
...

uintptr_t objStart = 0x0;
uintptr_t jmpBack = 0x0;
Ent* ents[255];
Ent* entsptr;

void hook()
{
    __asm {
        movss xmm10, [rdi + 0x54]
        movss xmm11, [rdi + 0x58]
        mov EntityObjStart, rdi
        push rax
        push rcx
        push rdx
        push rbx
        push rsp
        push rbp
        push rsi
        push rdi
    }
    __asm {
        mov rax, ObjStart
        mov[entsptr], rax
    }

...
    for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++)
    {
        if (ents[i] == 0)
        {
            ents[i] = entsptr;
            break;
        }
    }
...
```

Sadly this won't work because MSVS doesn't support inline assembly for 64 bit. I tried doing a separate asm file and link that together with the project, which works, but I don't know how to pass in the pointers to the assembly file or get the RDI out so I can store it in the array...

If you guys have any suggestions, that would be amazing!

Comment: You tagged this "visual-studio".  I'm guessing you meant MSVC, but if you just meant that IDE, you can use it with a better compiler (like clang) that supports ASM blocks in 64-bit mode if you really want to use MSVC-style inline asm instead of GNU C inline asm.  But there are some quirks of MSVC's inline-asm support that aren't exactly identical in clang's implementation.  Or of course you could just write asm by hand.

Comment: My bad. I meant Vistual Studio using the built-in Visual C++ compiler aka MSVC. I have seen that other compilers have support for inline assembly, but I use Visual Studio and I tried to look up how to change compilers and it doesn't seem like you can. Well you could use Intels compiler, but that wouldn't work on my system...

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve. I would write an assembler function in a seperate file, and then pass the pointer to the register array to it. Then you can simply move all the registers to that array, as you see fit. However, due to the function call, the registers may have been different values, but this is already the case in your above function as well.

Comment: The goal is to just get a list of all the entities that uses the function that I hook :)
I have never passed anything to a separate asm file before, can you point me in the right direction?